# Reverse digits in a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, integer, reverse

I want to reverse digits in a number in python. Here are my two implementations.

**One:** convert the number into string and reverse each char in it

```
number = 2376674032

number_s = str(number)
index = len(number_s) - 1
str_list = []
while index > -1:
    str_list.append(number_s[index])
    index -= 1

result = int("".join(str_list))
print(result)
```

**Two:** using simple mathematics

```
number = 2376674032

N = 0
K = number
R = number % 10
while K > 0:
    N = N*10 + R
    K = K // 10
    R = K % 10

result = N
print(result)
```

As I'm pretty new to python programming, so could someone help me with the following questions:

- with the first approach, will `"".join(str_list)` produce a new string with each list element? if so is a better way to concatenate strings in python(something similar to `StringBuffer` in java)
- which of the implementations is better from performance perspective?

Comment: Your first method can be replaced by `int(''.join(str(number)[::-1]))`. As far as performance, benchmark them and find out!

Comment: @CoryKramer what about concatenating arbitrary strings?

Answer (score 4):

You can reverse a string using -1 as the step in a slice. So this works:

```
number = 2376674032
number_s = str(number)
reverse_s = number_s[::-1]
reversed = int(reverse_s)
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to reverse a number …..input it as string format , and do this:

```
number="8374783246837"
revnumber=number[::-1]
```

Done
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 1234
a = int("".join(reversed(str(a))))
```

This will give a = 4321

reversed functions returns an iterable object.
If we do :

```
a = list(reversed(str(a)))
```

it will return [“3”,”2″,”1″]. We have then joined it and converted into int.

Answer (score 0):

To make the number an `integer` type, we have to use the `int` function, as below:

```
numbers=str(123456)
#or numbers="123456"

print((int(numbers[::-1])))
print((type(int(numbers[::-1]))))
```

output:

> 654321
> <class 'int'>

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in a single line as well using [::-1]

print(int(str(int(input()))[::-1]))

Answer (score -2):

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````
#here is my answer . you can do it using simple recursion
# count digits recursively 
def reverse_digits(n):
    # base case 
    if n == 0:
        pass 
    #recursive case
    else:
        print(n%10,end='')
        return reverse_digits(n//10)
# reverse 123
reverse_digits(123)
````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Why are you editing your post to make it completely unreadable?

Comment: Chris, I just reposted it … new to stack overflow … so wanted to try out myself the formatting stuff … I didn't know that you had already edited it … just catching up with the rules